# Integration of a composition with an uknow function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know:
$$\int_4^9(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}+f(x))dx=2$$
$$ \int_4^7f(x)dx=-8$$
And I want to calculate:
$$ \int_7^9f(x)dx$$

My first idea was to calculate  $\int_4^9(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1})$ then subtract the result from 2. Now sum $-8$ with the result of the subtraction. Is the correct way? If yes, how should I integrate $\int(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1})$ ?

Comment: I dont think you´re right. The equation is $\int_4^9\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1} \, dx-8+\int_7^9 f(x) \, dx=2$ Thus $\int_7^9 f(x) \, dx=2- \int_4^9\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1} \, dx+8$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt x=y\implies x=y^2\implies dx=2y\ dy$

$$\int_4^9\dfrac{\sqrt x\ dx}{x+1}=\int_2^3\dfrac{2y^2\ dy}{y^2+1}=2\int_2^3\dfrac{(y^2+1)-1\ dy}{y^2+1}=?$$

Comment: Split $-1$ and $(y^2+1)$ ?

Comment: @Marco, $$\dfrac{y^2}{y^2+1}=\dfrac{y^2+1-1}{y^2+1}=1-\dfrac1{y^2+1}$$

Comment: so my final result is $x-tan^-1(x)$ ? For the limits 2 and 3, my result looks different from wolfram or geogebra

Comment: @Marco, Please share the results of wolfram & that of yours

Comment: Wolfram and Geogebra's result is aout $2.41$ , my result is $1.72$, $$(2*3-2tan^-1(3))-(2*2-2tan^-1(2))$$

Comment: @Marco, $$\tan^{-1}3+\tan^{-1}2=\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\dfrac12+\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\dfrac13$$  $$=\pi-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1/2+1/3}{1-1/2\cdot1/3}=\pi-\dfrac\pi4$$